# Apache 2.2.22 - Random Vhost misrouting

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I have a Apache 2.2.22 + PHP 5.4.9 running on a Ubuntu 12.04

I'm hosting three sites here. For that, i have 2 virtual host pointing to three differents folders.

For example, this is one Vhost for *domain1*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com
        ServerAdmin support@server.com
    DocumentRoot /mnt/htdocs/domain1.com/public
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /mnt/htdocs/domain1.com/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain1.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain1.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The this here is that the 1% of the hits goes to incorrect folder. the other 99% goes to the correct folder and resolve the correct domain/code.

Example of the error in domain1.com's error log

```
[Fri Feb 14 15:21:45 2014] [error] [client 10.183.250.134] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sitemap\\SitemapServiceProvider' not found in /mnt/htdocs/domain1.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123, referer: http://www.site2.com/someurl
```

This service provider doesn't exists because domain2.com is routed to domain1.com's folder.

This error is COMPLETELY RANDOM. If I reload the error page, the site render ok.

I checked all the lines of vhosts, erasing all the non critical to keep it simple but the error continues.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory... I'd experienced an issue like this myself. Here's my thinking:

Do you have a

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

line in your **httpd.conf**? Preferably before all your **VirtualHost** definitions.

If you don't have a line like this, add it. If you have a line that explicitly specifies an IP, like so:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80
```

then either change it to match your **VirtualHost** definitions, or vice versa. Bottom line is that your **NameVirtualHost** line needs to match all your **VirtualHost** lines. Finally, there should be only **one** NameVirtualHost line for the entire Apache config... i.e. across all the .conf files, you should only see one NameVirtualHost line. You can use something like:

```
grep -r ^NameVirtualHost /etc/apache2/*
```

to locate all of them.

If you have more than one **NameVirtualHost** and/or all your **VirtualHost** don't match your **NameVirtualHost** definition, you will get unpredictable/inconsistent behaviour from Apache.

Comment: Thanks @rouben. I found NameVirtualHost *:80 on ports.conf

All my VirtualHost are <VirtualHost *:80> and has a 
`
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias www.domain1.com
`